# Calculate $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{t^2}{n^2}\right) e^{-izt}dt$

Tags: integration, infinite-product

Calculate
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{t^2}{n^2}\right) e^{-izt}dt$$
Any suggestions please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: $$\frac{\sin\pi t}{\pi t}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{t^2}{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: Taking into account Anastasiya-Romanova's comment, I suppose that you will end with some $\text{Si}$ (sine integral).

Comment: Hint: Fourier transform, top-hat function, convolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the integral
\begin{align}
I = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left[ \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 - \frac{t^{2}}{k^{2}} \right) \right] e^{-i z t} \, dt
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 - \frac{t^{2}}{k^{2}} \right) = \frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}
\end{align}
for which
\begin{align}
I = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t} \, e^{-i z t} \, dt.
\end{align}
By direct integration this leads to
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{i}{2 \pi} \left[ Ei(-i(z+\pi)t) - Ei(i(z+\pi)t) \right]_{-\pi}^{\pi} \\
&= \frac{i}{2\pi} \left[ Ei(-i(\pi^{2}+ \pi z)) - Ei(i(\pi^{2} - \pi z)) + Ei(-i(\pi^{2} - \pi z)) - Ei(i(\pi^{2} - \pi z)) \right]
\end{align}
where $Ei(z)$ is the exponential integral defined by
\begin{align}
Ei(z) = - \int_{-z}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t} \, dt.
\end{align}
Converting from the Exponential integrals to sine and cosine integrals,
defined by
\begin{align}
Ci(z) &= - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(t)}{t} \, dt = \frac{1}{2}\left(Ei(iz)+ Ei(-iz) \right) \\
Si(z) &= - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} \, dt = \frac{1}{2i} \left( Ei(z)- Ei(-iz) \right) + \frac{\pi}{2}, 
\end{align}
the integral is seen as
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{\sin(\pi^{2})}{2 \pi^{2}} \left[ Ci(\pi^{2} + \pi z) + Ci(\pi^{2} - \pi z) \right] \\
& \, \, \, + \frac{1}{\pi^{2}} \left( 2 \sin^{2}(\pi^{2}) - \cos^{2}(\pi^{2}) \right) \left[ Si(\pi^{2} + \pi z) + Si(\pi^{2} - \pi z) \right].
\end{align}

Comment: Can you please tell us what are these "$Ei(-i(z+\pi)t)$" etc and all? The solution is really impressive but I am not able to catch the definitions of these stuff. Thanks

Comment: @AnjanDebnath The definitions of the functions used have been added.